# php function returns false

Tags: php

The following PHP function returns the n-th weekday of a month, e.g. the 3rd Wednesday in January 2012 in the form 18-1-2012:

```
<?php
  function giveNthDay($month, $year, $no, $day) {
     $counter = 0;
     for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++) { //Schleife für 31 Tage
         if(!checkdate($month, $i, $year)) { //wenn datum nicht existiert (bspw. 30. februar) zu nächstem schleifendurchlauf springen
             continue;
         } else {
             if(date('l', strtotime($i.'-'.$month.'-'.$year))==$day) { //wenn generiertes Datum gleicher Wochentag wie gesuchter Tag $day
                 $counter++; //dann $counter um eins erhöhen
                 if($counter==$no) { //falls $counter==$no, also falls bspw. DRITTER ($no==$counter==3) Mittwoch gefunden, Datum zurückgeben
                     return     $i.'-'.$month.'-'.$year;
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return false; //existiert nicht, bspw. fünfter Sonntag gibt es nicht in jedem Monat
  }
?>
```

If the date doesn't exist (e.g. 5th Friday in January 2012), it returns false.

This works fine for examples like:

```
giveNthDay(1, 2012, 3, "Wednesday");
giveNthDay(1, 2020, 3, "Wednesday");
giveNthDay(1, 2031, 3, "Wednesday");
```

but from

```
giveNthDay(1, 2038, 3, "Wednesday");
```

on, it returns false even though every January has more than 3 Wednesdays!

I tried hard to find out what the reason for this strange behaviour is but I can't figure it out. Can anyone help me?

Comment: An if block that just does a continue is really gross.  Have you heard of an "else if"?   Or maybe the `getdate()` function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2038 is out of scope, max date being 2037 (on a 32 bits architecture). `time()` is a unix timestamp (starting the 1970-1-1 00:00:00).

Comment: The DateTime class should be used for dates after 2038.

Comment: `date('c', pow(2,31)); > 2038-01-19T04:14:08+01:00`, but my system is 64 bits, so I can grow bigger: `echo strftime('%c', pow(2,62)); Tue Jun 19 08:45:04 109626219` Your next server will be able to deal with 2038 I guess.